# Can somebody give me an example of getting the content of a page from a URL in vb.net for windows 8?

Tags: vb.net, http, url, httpwebrequest

I am very new to vb/.net and I'm trying to do something that I can do easily in classic vb. I want to get the source html for a webpage from the URL.

I'm using vb.net in Visual Studio Express for Windows 8.

I've read loads of stuff that talk about HttpWebRequest, but I can't get it to work properly.

I did at one point have it returning the html header, but I want to content of the page. Now, I can't even get it back to giving me the header. Ultimately, I want to process the html returned which I'll do (to begin with) the old-fashioned way and process the returned html as a string, but for now I'd like to just get the page.

The code I've got is:

```
Dim URL As String = "http://www.crayola.com/"
Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(URL))
txtHTML.Text = request.GetRequestStreamAsync().ToString()
```

Can anyone help me with an example to get me going please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use an Async method in a synchronous way, which won't make any sense.  If you're using .NET 4.5, you can try marking the calling method with `Async` and then using the `Await` keyword when calling `GetRequestStreamAsync`.

```
Public Sub MyDownloaderMethod() 

   Dim URL As String = "http://www.crayola.com/"
   Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest 
       = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(URL))

   ' Use the Await keyword wait for the async task to complete.      
   Dim response = request.GetResponseAsync()
   txtHTML.Text = response.GetResponseStream().ToString()

End Function
```

See the following MSDN article for more information on async programming with the Await keyword: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

**Edit**

You are receiving your error because you're trying to get the **Request** stream (what you send the server), and what you really want is the **Response** stream (what the server sends back to you).  I've updated my code to get the `WebResponse` from your `WebRequest` and then retrieve the stream from that.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'm get closer. Now I get "Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type." on the stream line. The code runs from the onload event of the page Private Async Sub On_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles pageRoot.Loaded. Am I OK making that Aysnc?

Comment: @TimFoster Glad I could help!  Not sure if you figured this part out yet but I've updated the code so that you look for the RESPONSE stream, and not the request stream like in your original example.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Shared Function GetWebPageString(ByVal address As Uri) As String
        Using client As New Net.WebClient()
            Return client.DownloadString(address)
        End Using
End Function
```

There is also `DownloadStringAsync` if you don't want to block

Comment: Thanks Matt, unfortunately, I get WebClient is not defined

Comment: @TimFoster - add `Imports System.Net` at the top of the class/module

Answer (score 0):

request.GetRequestStreamAsync() is probably not a method. I think you're cribbing code from a site where someone wrote their own add-on methods to HttpWebRequest. Try request.GetResponse() to return a response object, then in the response object you can inspect the stream and convert it to text if you need to.

Comment: `GetRequestStreamAsync` is an actual method on the `WebRequest` base class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getrequeststreamasync.aspx).  Regardless, I don't think that being async it could be used in the synchronous way that the OP showed in his example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Richthofen. I get an error on GetResponse() that it's not a member of HttpWebRequest. The intellisense gives me GetResponseAsync(), so I fiddled a little and got the following to produce "System.Net.ConnectStream", which isn't what I want either :( The code now reads:

Comment: Sorry, I can't edit the last post. My code is now:Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(URL))
        Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponseAsync.Result

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me in VB.Net 4.5

```
Public Async Sub GetHTML()

    Dim PageHTML as string
    Dim client As New HttpClient
    Dim getStringTask As Task(Of String) = client.GetStringAsync(PageURL)
    PageHTML = Await getStringTask
    MsgBox(PageHTML)

End Sub
```

Comment: This will block the UI since you are using Await